# Change Direction Of A Specific Column - Not Entire Row Or Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, telerik, radgrid

I have a little problem about the sort direction of a specific column in a Telerik RadGrid.  With Firebug we can find and change the direction of a table (master or detail) easily.  But there is not any class for a specific column to access.

How can I change the sort direction of a specific column, not the entire row or table in a Telerik RadGrid?

Comment: I think you better ask this question in Telerik forum: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet.aspx From what I know, their staff did good work on answering the question instead of ignoring you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the solution.
here is the example :

```
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PluginPath" FilterControlAltText="Filter PluginPath column" HeaderText="PluginPath" SortExpression="PluginPath" UniqueName="PluginPath"
      FilterImageToolTip="Filter">
          <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
          <ItemStyle  CssClass="PluginPath" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

and the css :

```
.PluginPath
{
    direction: ltr !important;
}
```

best wishes for stackoverflow users...